# How do I find out how much is spent?

Tags: combinatorics

I've had a few different answers for this question:

Laura simply must have a coffee when she arrives at uni in the morning, at lunch and in the afternoon. She comes to campus 5 days a week: 13 weeks in the Autumn session, 13 weeks in the Spring session and for 4 weeks of examinations. Her choice of coffee costs $3.20 a cup. After buying 5 coffees, the sixth is free. How much does she spend on coffee in one year?

So I've calculated that she spends 150 days on campus, so she must drink 150 x 3 = 450 coffees all year.

The cost of 6 coffees, is the cost of 5.

5 x $3.20 = $16

She buys 6 coffees, 450/6= 75 times.

So altogether, she spends 75 x $16 = $1200 on coffee a year.

This is my original answer. I'm not sure if I've done everything right. Would be helpful if anyone could give me a few pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply mind in this way: if every $5$ coffees the sixth one is free, then every two days she will pay just $5$ coffees.

Indeed, three coffee per day means six every 2 days. Namely $5$ paid + $1$ free.

Now it shall be easier to do the maths!

**Final Hint**

She pays for $5$ coffees every $2$ days...

Comment: I think you have Fourier transformed this question. It seems a lot easier now.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг lol! Nice one and thank you! :D